# Preview problem on "iPhoto imported" clips in iMovie

Tags: photos.app, imovie, movie

I've a strange problem with iMovie : I can preview movie clips that I've directly imported into iMovie, but the ones that have been imported from my camera by iPhoto have a problem : the displayed preview when I do a "mouse-over" is showing another movie clip (always the same, for every movie clip)

Is there a way to ask iPhoto or iMovie to "rebuild" this previews ?

EDIT : Is there a way to rebuild the cache of iPhoto ?

Answer (score 1):

Hold cmd+opt while launching iPhoto.  Good luck! :-)